# in over-the-top mock-sci parody

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does "in over-the-top mock-sci parody" imply? the excessive parody of Hirst's work of scientific models? My main problem is with the complex word *mock-sci* in this context.

> Some of Hirst's work was shown at the Gagosian Gallery, New York in 2000 at an exhibition called, in over-the-top mock-sci parody, Theories, Models, Methods, Approaches, Assumptions, Results and Findings.

From *[Art and Science](https://books.google.com/books?id=iiE3RsvK248C&pg=PA141&lpg=PA141)* (2005) by Siân Ede.

Answer (score 1):

"Over-the-top" doesn't mean "excessive" here so much as it means "obvious" or "obviously ridiculous".

Don't get too tripped-up by "mock-sci". It's almost kind of a redundancy of the word "parody", so just try to read on. What it implies is an exhibition that, at least on the surface, has a similar look or flavor to a real exhibit about real science.

The rest of the paragraph supports this:

> Here were Hirst's characteristic life-size vitrines, some displaying fish swimming amongst gynaecological apparatus... Others encapsulate scientific experiment, all white coats and protective clothing, organised equipment display, tidy protocols... Much more shocking, however, is the exhibition catalogue, a haphazard arrangement of installation photographs [presented] mainly as a textbook [for] aspiring forensic scientists.

These are all imitations of science stuff, for the sake of parody.